# Updated to Rails 4.0, suddenly am passing two arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails

After updating Rails gem from 3.2 to 4.0, I am getting this error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 332ms

ActionView::Template::Error (wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)):
     5:       %th Activities
     6:       %th.w140
     7:   %tbody
     8:     - (list = latest_updates_list(@filter[:latest_updates_options])).each do |item|
     9:       %tr= latest_updates_item_helper(item)
    10:
    11:     - if list.length == 0
  app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:35:in `latest_updates_list'
  app/views/dashboard/_index.html.haml:8:in `_app_views_dashboard__index_html_haml__3752706349525323962_70305528188080'
  app/views/dashboard/index.html.haml:6:in `_app_views_dashboard_index_html_haml__2066908720777569268_70305520107720'
```

These are the gems that were updated:

```
Updated gems

Using activesupport 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)
Using builder 3.1.4 (was 3.0.4)

Using rack 1.5.5 (was 1.4.5)

Using actionpack 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using actionmailer 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)
Using activemodel 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using activerecord-deprecated_finders 1.0.4

Using arel 4.0.2 (was 3.0.3)
Using activerecord 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using railties 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)
Using coffee-rails 4.0.1 (was 3.2.2)

Using postgres_ext 2.0.0 (was 1.0.0)

Using sprockets 2.8.3 (was 2.2.2)

Using rails 4.0.0 (was 3.2.18)

Using sass 3.2.19 (was 3.3.5)
Using sass-rails 4.0.5 (was 3.2.6)
```

This is the 'latest_updates_list' method:

```
def latest_updates_list(option=nil )
    client_ids = current_user.actual_client_ids

    services = {}
    # binding.pry
    Service.where(:client_id => client_ids).each{|s| services[s.id] = {:name => s.name, :frequency_name => s.frequency_short_text, :per_hour => s.per_hour?} }
    #Service.where(true).each{|s| services[s.id] = {:name => s.name, :frequency_name => s.frequency_short_text, :per_hour => s.per_hour?} }

    reports = []
    invoices = []
    tickets = []
    employees = []

    list = []
    case option.to_sym
    when :reports
      reports = Report.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_report?)
    when :invoices
      invoices = Invoice.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_invoice?)
    when :tickets
      tickets = Ticket.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_ticket?)
    when :employees
      employees = Employee.for_latest_updates(current_user.filter_client_id, client_ids) if user_admin?
    else
      reports = Report.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_report?)
      invoices = Invoice.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_invoice?)
      tickets = Ticket.for_latest_updates(client_ids) if (user_admin? || user_can_ticket?)
      employees = Employee.for_latest_updates(current_user.filter_client_id, client_ids) if user_admin?
    end

    list += reports.collect do |r|
       {
         :date => r.updated_at,
         :entity => 1,
         :status_text => latest_update_report_status_text(r),
         :reports_services_text => latest_updates_reports_services_text(r, r.reports_services),
         :report_id => r.id}
    end unless reports.empty?

    list += invoices.collect do |i|
       {
         :date => i.updated_at,
         :entity => 2,
         :status_text => latest_update_invoice_status_text(i),
         :invoice_reports_services_text => latest_updates_invoice_reports_services_text(services, i.reports),
         :invoice_id => i.id}
    end unless invoices.empty?

    list += tickets.collect do |t|
       {
         :date => latest_update_ticket_date(t),
         :entity => 3,
         :status_text => latest_update_ticket_status_text(t),
         :description => t.description_text,
         :ticket_id => t.id}
    end unless tickets.empty?

    list += employees.collect do |e|
       {
         :date => e.updated_at,
         :entity => 4,
         :description => e.text_for_stream,
         :employee_id => e.employee_id}
    end unless employees.empty?

    sorted_list = list.sort{|a, b| a[:date].to_i <=> b[:date].to_i}
    list = sorted_list.reverse!
    list = list.take(50)
  end
```

When I comment out the first 3 'list += ....do...', then the app will load, apart from not getting the info that they get. I haven't changed any of this code, so it must be due to the gem update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was a problem with postgres_ext gem being outdated.